# BareMetal order fails for win 2008 sp1

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I opened an issue for Softlayer API on github.
https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-ruby/issues/120

and had a chat on SL portal with one guy who recommended to post it here as right people are here. :)

Just quick description(more details in the issue). Bare metal order doesn't work with WIN_2008-STD-R2-SP1_64 os code, but it does with WIN_2008-STD-R2-SP2_64 and other linux codes.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you are using the softlayer-ruby client it only orders fast servers (I mean it orders servers from the package 200 and hourly servers). These servers do not have available the OS "WIN_2008-STD-R2-SP1_64" that's why you see the error. Now you can see that the OS is available in the portal because likely you selected a server which uses another package, the easy way to know if you selected in the portal a server from another package is verifying if the server has the option hourly, if it does not have the option the server belongs to another package. If you want to order the server using the API you need to use the placeOrder method

see this article to understand how to use the method:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/bpotter/going-further-softlayer-api-python-client-part-3

here a example using Ruby

```
# Order a Bare Metal Server.
#
# Build a SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order object for a new
# server order and pass it to the SoftLayer_Product_Order API service to order
# it. In this care we'll order a Xeon 3460 server with 2G RAM, 100mbit NICs,
# 2000GB bandwidth, a 500G SATA drive, CentOS 5 32-bit, and default server
# order options. See below for more details.
#
# Important manual pages:
# http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order
# http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server
# http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price
# http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder
# 
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder
#
# License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
# Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc.<sldn@softlayer.com>

require 'rubygems'
require 'softlayer_api'
require 'json'

# Your SoftLayer API username.
USERNAME = 'set me'

# Your SoftLayer API key.
API_KEY = 'set me'

# The number of servers you wish to order in this configuration.
quantity = 1

# Where you'd like your new server provisioned.
# This can either be the id of the datacenter you wish your new server to be
# provisioned in or the string 'FIRST_AVAILABLE' if you have no preference
# where your server is provisioned.
# Location id 3     = Dallas
# Location id 18171 = Seattle
# Location id 37473 = Washington, D.C.
location = 'AMSTERDAM'

# The id of the SoftLayer_Product_Package you wish to order.
# In this case the Intel Xeon 3460's package id is 145.
package_id = 146

# Build a skeleton SoftLayer_Hardware_Server object to model the hostname and
# domain we want for our server. If you set quantity greater then 1 then you
# need to define one hostname/domain pair per server you wish to order.
hardware = [
  {
    'hostname' => 'test', # The hostname of the server you wish to order.
    'domain' => 'example.org' # The domain name of the server you wish to order.
  }
]

# Build a skeleton SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price objects. These objects contain
# much more than ids, but SoftLayer's ordering system only needs the price's id
# to know what you want to order.

# Every item in SoftLayer's product catalog is assigned an id. Use these ids
# to tell the SoftLayer API which options you want in your new server. Use
# the getActivePackages() method in the SoftLayer_Account API service to get
# a list of available item and price options per available package.
prices = [
  { 'id' => 172_32 }, # Single Processor Quad Core Xeon 1270 - 3.40GHz  (Sandy Bridge) - 1 x 8MB cache w/HT
  { 'id' => 637 }, # RAM 2 GB DDR2 667
  { 'id' => 682 }, # CentOS 5.x (32 bit)
  { 'id' => 876 }, # Disk Controller
  { 'id' => 20 }, # 500 GB SATA II
  { 'id' => 342 }, # 20000 GB Bandwidth
  { 'id' => 273 }, # 100 Mbps Public & Private Network Uplinks
  { 'id' => 55 }, # Host Ping
  { 'id' => 58 }, # Automated Notification
  { 'id' => 420 }, # Unlimited SSL VPN Users & 1 PPTP VPN User per account
  { 'id' => 418 }, # Nessus Vulnerability Assessment & Reporting
  { 'id' => 21 }, # 1 IP Address
  { 'id' => 57 }, # Email and Ticket
  { 'id' => 906 } # Reboot / KVM over IP
]

# Build a skeleton SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Hardware_Server object
# containing the order you wish to place.
order_template = {
  'quantity' => quantity,
  'location' => location,
  'packageId' => package_id,
  'prices' => prices,
  'hardware' => hardware
}

# Declare the API client to use the SoftLayer_Product_Order API service
client = SoftLayer::Client.new(username: USERNAME, api_key: API_KEY)
product_order_service = client.service_named('SoftLayer_Product_Order')

# verifyOrder() will check your order for errors. Replace this with a call to
# placeOrder() when you're ready to order. Both calls return a receipt object
# that you can use for your records.
#
# Once your order is placed it'll go through SoftLayer's provisioning process.
# When it's done you'll have a new SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest object and CCI ready
# to use.

begin
  receipt = product_order_service.verifyOrder(order_template)
  puts receipt
rescue StandardError => exception
  puts "There was an error in your order: #{exception}"
end
```

Regards

Comment: ok, this makes sense. However, I don't care now as I got this from SL:
We will discontinue offering the Windows Server 2008 Standard and Data Center Edition products on Wednesday, November 23, 2016 and will discontinue support on Friday, March 31, 2016.